# How to get maximum value of column "No." with respect to column "Name" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 3 column in a table. In column "Name" there are name and in column "No." there are no. with respect to column "Name" So here, I want to find which is a maximum no. of Jawed, Rahul, Vinay.

[image: Na]

Below is the expected result.

[image]

Comment: Below is the expected result.

Name No. Max_no.
Jawed 5 
Jawed 7 Max
Jawed 3 
Rahul 25 
Rahul 56 Max
Rahul 56 Max
Rahul 45 
Vinay 67 
Vinay 3 
Vinay 75 Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the max_index of No. regarding the Name column :

```
max_value = df.Name[df['No.'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: Answer is something else like need OP. Accepting only by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for compare `max` values by original column:

```
df['Max no.'] = np.where(df.groupby('Name')['No.'].transform('max').eq(df['No.']), 'Max','')
```